# What causes the leak sanitizer to behave differently for T* and T*& in my struct implementation?

Tags: c++, leak-sanitizer

why -fsanitize=address,leak behaves differently for **T*** and **T*&**?

I created a struct for pointer_ownership

```
template<class T>
struct pointer_ownership
{
    T* ptr;
    bool is_owner;
    pointer_ownership(T*& t_ptr, bool t_is_owner)
        : ptr(t_ptr), is_owner(t_is_owner)
    {
    }
};
```

And a main function

```
int main()
{
   auto *a = new int(32);
   pointer_ownership po(a, true);
   return 0;
}
```

When I build the code using below command and run it **no leak sanitizer error is generated**.

```
g++ -fsanitize=address,leak main.cpp  && ./a.out
```

But if I change **T*** to **T*&** in pointer_ownership struct then **leak sanitizer error is generated**.

Why leak sanitizer isn't showing error in case of **T***?

Comment: This is a QOI issue perhaps? GCC 13 does show report a leak here https://godbolt.org/z/GYsxh94ME What version of GCC are you running?

Comment: g++ (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) 11.3.0

Comment: clang is showing in the both cases. I suggest to use it.

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference (consistent with previous comments noting that your symptom goes away with a different compiler and also with an updated version of your compiler).    You may wish to add a destructor to your `pointer_ownership` class that releases the pointer (that will reduce the chances of the dynamically allocated `int` being detected as unreleased by the sanitizer).

Comment: In the -fsanitize option if address is removed then leak sanitizer is working fine even in the case of "T*" but if address is added then leak sanitizer doesn't work and program returns 0